# Bootstrapping of multiple values using boot::boot()

Tags: r

I try to estimate confidence intervals for several parameters of a nonlinear model using bootstrapping. Right now, I do bootstrapping for for each parameter individually. Therefore I have to gererate the model serveral times.

Here is an example:

```
library(boot)

# generate some data:
x <- rnorm(300, mean = 5, sd = 2)
y <- xvalues^2*rnorm(300, mean = 1.5, sd = 1) + rnorm(300, mean = 3, sd = 1)
data <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)  

# this is my model: nls(y ~ b1*x^2+b2, data = data, start = list(b1 = 1.5,b2 = 3)) 

# functions for bootstrapping:
getParamB1 <- function(x1, idx){
    data <- x1 %>%
        dplyr::slice(idx) 

    model <- nls(y ~ b1*x^2+b2, data = data, start = list(b1 = 1.5,b2 = 3))

    coef(model)[['b1']]
}

getParamB2 <- function(x1, idx){
    data <- x1 %>%
        dplyr::slice(idx) 

    model <- nls(y ~ b1*x^2+b2, data = data, start = list(b1 = 1.5,b2 = 3))

    coef(model)[['b2']]
}

# Calculate bootstrap confidence intervals
btrpB1 <- boot(data, statistic = getParamB1, R=200)
btrpB2 <- boot(data, statistic = getParamB2, R=200)
ciB1 <- boot.ci(btrpB1)
ciB2 <- boot.ci(btrpB2)
```

This is of course not very nice code. Is there a way to estiamte confidence intervals for several parameters (here b1 and b2) at once?

Comment: just use `coef(model)`

Comment: I like to use bootstrapping. The above is just a toy example.

Comment: ?Does the comment not answer your question - make your function return multiple parameters. (ps why not use `data <- x1 [idx, ]` to reduce overhead)

Comment: Ah, ok, now I understand. I did not know that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
library(boot)

# generate some data:
x <- rnorm(300, mean = 5, sd = 2)
y <- x^2 * rnorm(300, mean = 1.5, sd = 1) + rnorm(300, mean = 3, sd = 1)
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

m1 <- nls(y ~ b1 * x^2 + b2, data = df, start = list(b1 = 1.5, b2 = 3)) 

boot.coef <- function(mod, data, indices) {
  assign(deparse(mod$data), data[indices, ])
  m <- eval(mod$call)
  return(coef(m))
}

results <- boot(data = df, statistic = boot.coef,
                R = 1000, mod = m1)
```